# What is the probability of a poker hand (5 cards) containing at least one club?

Tags: probability, poker

Could this be calculated using the complement of the event? And if so, how?

Comment: Yes, calculate the probability of the complement: the complement of "5 cards containing at least one club" is "5 cards containing no clubs".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, and using the complement is probably the simplest way. The complement of a hand having at least one club is a hand having no clubs, so the desired probability is

$$1 - \frac{\binom{39}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted? This is a perfect answer. How could this have been better?

Comment: IDK who downvoted it but he answered my question perfectly, as you pointed out.

Comment: When an asker asks a very poor question, as you did here, sometimes users who choose to answer  questions that others believe be closed and not answered, like yours was closed by five other users, may be penalized for answering it in the first place.